# google play store insufficient storage lenovo A5000

Tags: android

every time i try to download app or update apps from google store ,said"insufficient storage" but i have 11GB of space in my memory card and my phone is lenovo A5000  .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMuIc.png)

Comment: Because apps are installed in the internal memory (which is the so called RAM). This is fixed and can't be upgraded. You can use apps such as [link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) to move your apps onto the SD Card, but it requires it to have a second partition, formatted as ext4. By the way, your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), on a **programming** Q&A site

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about how to use an Android device. You might be able to find answers over at [android.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, this is related to `Internal Storage`

**Second**, follow the steps:

1. Settings
2. Storage
3. Internal Storage
4. Click on `Cache data`
5. Ok

I hope it helps!!

Comment: @Abdelrhman Swelm check this out

Comment: ohhhh ....  thank you it really worked

Comment: @AbdelrhmanSwelm Please accept the answer so that others can also benefit from it !!

Answer (score -1):

Try moving files onto the memory card manually (I perfer astro file manager) because the internal memory is all it checks for space. If it's not full than try changing the version of the app store.